# session variables mysteriously disappear in IE7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, internet-explorer-7

I can't login to our Rails 2.3.8 application any more since a recent update to Windows. This is IE version 7.0.5730.13.

In my login controller, we authenticate the account and put the user AR in session[:user], then redirect to a main menu.

However, the redirect fails, because when the main menu controller checks to see if the user is logged in, session[:user] is now nil!

Please note this works fine in Firefox and Safari.

HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your cookies configuration. It seems something related.